# Chrome latest v68 zoom page using ctrl + scroll

Tags: google-chrome

Today I update the Google Chrome browser version to 68 and Now I couldn't zoom in or zoom out a page by using Ctrl + Mouse Scroll action, Do they have changed the page zoom In/Out shortcut keys on Chrome 68 ?

OS: Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS

Comment: I have exactly the same problem. I've updated yesterday to chrome 68.0.3440.75. I am using Ubuntu. I've tried restarting the browser, tried incognito, tried a clean profile.

Comment: I have the same problem in Chrome 68.0.3440.106 with Ctrl + touchpad scroll. Only with laptop touchpad, so zooming with real mouse wheel scroll works. Restarting or incognito window does not help. This affects only Chrome, zooming with Ctrl+ touchpad scroll still works in other applications like EoG or Nautilus file manager. I have Debian 9 (upstream for Ubuntu). This might be a Linux specific issue. I also submitted a report through Help -> Report Issue.

Comment: I'm experiencing the same problem.

Comment: There is an issue opened : https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=878694

Answer (score 2):

According to [this](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=878694) discussion, the issue is not getting fixed. However, there is a [chrome extension](https://github.com/hempe/ctrlZoom) mentioned there, which solves the problem. [Here](https://www.mattcutts.com/blog/how-to-install-a-chrome-extension-from-github/) you can find how to install it, if you never did this.

Edit: It's now available on the [chrome web store](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ctrl-zoom/indpmklmjbcfkbnbhoknlggplddednhp)

I did not write this extension, all credits to the original author.

Answer (score 0):

My chrome is running on Version 68.0.3440.75 (64-bit). I'm not facing the same. Its working properly for me. Just restart the browser and check again!

Comment: Yes I did , But couldn't get it working, It's just ignoring the Ctrl button input, Instead of zoom In/Out it's scrolling up and down

Answer (score 0):

Good to see I'm not the only one.

I have 2 Fedora 28 systems: a laptop with a touchpad, and a desktop with a mouse. Both are on Chrome 68. The laptop lost the ability to zoom with CTRL + the simulated mouse wheel. The desktop can still zoom with the CTRL + the real mousewheel.

I'm going to try plugging in a mouse to the laptop and see what happens.

I submitted a report through Help -> Report Issue. I would recommend you do the same.

Comment: Zoom with the mouse wheel works fine. It is just an issue with the touchpad. I also pulled in a libinput update that same day, but the list of changes (https://lists.freedesktop.org/archives/wayland-devel/2018-July/039137.html) makes me lean towards it being more of a problem with Chrome, especially since it still works with other applications like GIMP.

Comment: I don't recall being given one. I went to the Help menu, "Report an issue..."